# Tkinter library causes program to freeze

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, freeze

In our office, my PC, our Test server, and our Production server are all running Windows 7. I'm writing code in Python 2.7 and generating an executable with Pyinstaller (using the onefile option, but not windowed).

I've written a GUI program using Tkinter that runs fine on my PC and on the Test server, but when I delivered it to Production, it won't run. The standard output window opens, but the GUI window doesn't.

After trying various things, I decided to try a bare-bones test. I wrote and compiled the following code:

```
print("Hello World")
Pause = raw_input("Press the <ENTER> key to continue...")
```

It ran fine on all three machines. Then I added one line:

```
from Tkinter import *
print("Hello World")
Pause = raw_input("Press the <ENTER> key to continue...")
```

It worked on my PC and on Test, but not on Production. It just opens the standard output window and sits there until I close it.

I tried the same thing in Python 3.4 and got the same results.

I don't know what to look for. Why would the act of loading the Tkinter library (without even using it) cause a program to hang?

Comment: is your test system and production system using the same architecture (specifically bit width, are they both 64-bit systems)?

Comment: @13smith_oliver: It would be on the production system because the windows distribution of python comes with Tkinter built in.

Comment: @Bob have you checked to see if all your computers have the same version of python? If your production system is not 2.7 it might cause this problem. I know python 3 does not use `raw_input` and uses `input` instead.

Comment: @13smith_oliver OP is trying to run the frozen .exe on the production system therefore shouldn't need tkinter or python installed.

Comment: @Novel: Ah I didn't realize the OP has made a stand alone exe. You are right it could be an issue related to 32bit vs 64bit.

Comment: Test and Production do not have Python on them at all. I'm using _Pyinstaller --onefile_ on my PC to create an executable that contains all the code it needs.

Comment: All three systems are 64-bit. My PC is running Microsoft .NET v 4.6.01055, and Test and Production are both v 4.5.51209

Comment: Just for fun, try using a real import (`import Tkinter as tk`) instead of your evil wildcard import. It won't matter to python but maybe there's a pyinstaller quirk that preventing a complete import.

Comment: BTW, the --onefile option just puts all the code in a self-extracting zip file. Unzipping the file before each run is kinda slow, so you would see a speed improvement if you didn't use that option.

Comment: @Novel: Thanks. I was under the impression that --onefile put all the code into one file so it didn't have to import external libraries at runtime. (I'm fairly new to Python, if you couldn't tell.)

Comment: I tried `import Tkinter as tk` but that didn't work either. To add to the confusion, a coworker wrote a program that works just fine on all three systems. His code begins with: `from tkinter import *`  `from tkinter import ttk`  `from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory`  I had him compile my code, but it still doesn't work in Production.

Comment: _FLASH!_ Compiling the program without --onefile resolved the problem (at least for the "Hello World" example)! I'm about to try it with the actual application itself.

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks, @Novel !